# In Bidiots, what do the texts from the art buyers mean?

Tags: jackbox-party-pack-2

The texts that players receive from art buyers range from incredibly useful to obviously meaningless. For example, a text along the lines of

> Don't let *player* fool you, they know exactly how much this piece is worth.

provides valuable information that can influence my actions for that round, while

> Secretly fart on *player*! Do it!

is unlikely to affect my general gameplay strategy.

Not all of the messages are this easily deciphered. For example, I've received messages similar to both of these:

> *player* is low on cash. Don't waste a screw on them.
>
> *player* has less than $1000. Don't waste a screw on them.

While the second is very clear, the first is vague. Do they both mean the same thing, or can the first refer to a player with slightly more than $1000?

Other messages are even less clear, so much so that I'm unsure whether they mean anything at all. If I receive

> You should consider *player* to be your enemy.

does that provide me with any information at all?

What, if anything, should I be taking away from the texts?

Answer (score 2):

> > > *Don't let player fool you, they know exactly how much this piece is worth.*
> >
> > provides valuable information that can influence my actions for that round...

Yes, since they know the value of the painting, they're likely to be more willing to actually bid on it (or stop suddenly when it's about to go from profit to loss). If they bid pretty vigorously, it may be a tell that the painting is highly-valued. If they're more reticent, you might not want to be so eager.

> > *player is low on cash. Don't waste a screw on them.*
> >
> > *player has less than $1000. Don't waste a screw on them.*
>
> While the second is very clear, the first is vague. Do they both mean the same thing, or can the first refer to a player with slightly more than $1000?

They both give you similar advice: that if the bid price on the painting has gone up and you attempt to screw this player, you will waste the screw because they cannot afford to bid.

> > *You should consider player to be your enemy.*
>
> does that provide me with any information at all?

It generally means they are winning the game based on projected final score, and you should attempt to:

- prevent them from acquiring any more art
- make them use up cash on relatively cheap lots, so they can't buy more valuable paintings
- convince them to take loans they cannot recoup the interest on
- coerce them into overbidding on art you know the value of and taking a loss